# Quick and dirty way to edit scans

Tags: image-manipulation, scanner

I've got a lot of documents that I want to scan that require only modest editing.

Mainly trimming the edges, splitting in two (when I scan two pages in one scan), and possibly adjust the perspective like camscanner.

**NOTE:** (You layout a quadrilangle, camscanner then adjusts the perspective so the quadriangle becomes a square).

Gimp and a couple of other programs can do this, but it seems to me to be significant overkill.

What other options are there for doing these tasks?

Comment: What format are your documents in?

Comment: @Evan Teitlman, whatever formats sane returns.

Answer (score 1):

[unpaper](http://unpaper.berlios.de/) does all sorts of basic post-scan processing.

> `unpaper` is a post-processing tool for scanned sheets of paper, especially for book pages that have been scanned from previously created photocopies. The main purpose is to make scanned book pages better readable on screen after conversion to PDF.

Comment: unpaper looks like an interesting tool, however it doesn't do what I am asking for.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that it doesn't do trapezoidal correction.